# How to properly construct a favicon.ico response when writing an embedded web server

Tags: html, http, server, favicon

I am trying to write an embedded application that serves it own web pages, and I'd like to get the favicon behavior working correctly.  However, I think I'm formatting the response incorrectly.  Why is this not generating a fav icon in my browser tab (I'm guessing wrong Content-type or something similar).  I have complete control over what appears in the headers & body of the response:

```
curl -v localhost:7777/favicon.ico
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7777 (#0)
> GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:7777
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 1958
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serve an image (PNG or ICO), not HTML.

Comment: So how do I do that?  Just send the raw icon bytes in the body of the response?  If so, what's the Content-Type?

Comment: Yes.  The content type should be the correct MIME type for whatever your image is, which you already have in the `data:` URI.